# typeWritter effect problem inside the useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the code bellow skips index 1 of my text, and  shows just "hllo world"

```
export default function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const index = useRef(0);
  const text = "hello world";

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setMessage((prevMessage) => prevMessage + text[index.current]);
      index.current++;
    }, 500);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{message}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But if i change this set state to

```
setMessage(text.substring(0, index.current));
```

this works well, and i dont know because.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any issue. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: `But if i change this set state to` - you then put exactly the same code as is already in your question! Which is the working code, and which the non-working?

Comment: i edited now, sorry, thanks for advice

Comment: It is really odd, somehow setMessage is not executed if index.current == 1 
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-dirac-ki6l8h?file=/src/App.js

Comment: yes its odd, i debug exactly same you,  its looks for some in the first execution he takes the index declare above, but in the next executions, he takes the value of index.current+1 before setState, and because of this, he skip the second execution to index.current == 2, i dont have ideia if is that.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that it is due to the fact that your callback

```
(prevMessage) => prevMessage + text[index.current]
```

is set in the queue when using setState, and runs asynchronously with increment of index. There is a possibility of data race.

When you use substring method, you get your string immediately, so it is perfectly synchronized with increment.

Please take a look at this [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), although I think it’s quite unobvious. But your case is a good example of this asynchrounous nature of setState.

Comment: shouldn't then the second letter appear then later? Currently it simply skips the execution for the second letter